# Eclipse ADT Open declaration in layout no longer default

Tags: java, android, eclipse, adt, eclipse-adt

For a couple of months my Eclipse began auto linking resource ids from Java code to the appropriate resource files in `res/` instead of `R.java` by command-clicking the generated Java variable. Now the default has been switched back - does anyone know how I can make the "Open Declaration in layout/***_*__**" the default again?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You Can Use Ctrl+Alt+Shift and click on res

or on Preferences -> General -> Editors -> Text Editors -> Hyperlinking you can change shortcut key

Comment: That does not solve the problem, doesn't it? The default option is still going to R.java, wihch is, IMHO, completely useless.

Comment: its work for me, i search alot about this problem and can't find better way

Answer (score 1):

For me to hide the option leading to R.java it was enough to change shortcut of "Preferences -> General -> Editors -> Text Editors -> Hyperlinking -> Open Declaration" to whatever key else that CTRL.